# Inserting list of dict as json array in Postgres from psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I have this table in postgres

```
CREATE TABLE target (
    a json
)
```

Which I would like to insert data to from psycopg2 using

```
import psycopg2
import psycopg2.extras as extras

# a is list of list of dicts
a = [[{'a':1,'b':2}, {'d':3,'e':2}],
      [{'a':3,'b':1}, {'e':2,'f':6}]]

# convert a to list of tuples containing extras.Json objects
a = [(extras.Json(x),) for x in a]

# insert a to the database
query = ('WITH ins (a) AS '
         '(VALUES %s) '
         'INSERT INTO target (a) '
         'SELECT ins.a '
         'FROM ins;')

cursor = conn.cursor()

extras.execute_values(cursor, query, a)
```

However I get the error: `column "a" is of type json but expression is of type text`

This example is simplified to make the question clearer (which is why the example is using the `WITH ins` statement as I need to join a table to it. I would have thought that this should work but for some reason it doesn't. My suspicion is the problem is that I load it in to ins first and maybe it loads it as a text instead of json there by default for some reason.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE target (
    a json
)

query = "INSERT INTO target VALUES %s"  

b = [[extras.Json(row)] for row in a] 
cur = con.cursor()
extras.execute_values(cur, query, b)
con.commit()

select * from target;
                  a                   
--------------------------------------
 [{"a": 1, "b": 2}, {"d": 3, "e": 2}]
 [{"a": 3, "b": 1}, {"e": 2, "f": 6}]
```

Simplified to just `INSERT` directly from the input values. I created them as a list as `execute_values` can take a sequence of sequences or a sequence of dictionaries(if using named parameters).

UPDATE:

```
query = ('WITH ins (a) AS '
         '(VALUES %s) '
         'INSERT INTO target (a) '
         'SELECT ins.a::json '
         'FROM ins;')
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Unfortunately the `WITH ins` statement is necessary as I need to join a table to it. Maybe I oversimplified too much. Is there anyway to adjust your method to work the `WITH ins ...`

Comment: Am I correct in assumning that this solution would load the json as a text into ins and then cast it from text to json when selecting?

Comment: Yes, that is the case.